# How To Populate Jtable Using rs2xml jar library

Tags: java, swing, jtable, multiple-resultsets

Dear friends i would like to know how to display the result set to jtable using rs2xml i know jtablename.setmodel(dbutils.setresultsettotable(rs)); but i would like to know that how to retriev all records and show them in jtablle my code is

```
private void search_by_topic() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try
    {
        SessionFactory sf;
        Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
        System.out.println("search_by_topic me agaya");
        cfg.configure("hiber_config/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        sf=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session ses=sf.openSession();
        ses.beginTransaction();
        Query qr1=ses.createQuery("from Topic where chapter_id=:chapter_id");
        qr1.setParameter("chapter_id", chap_id);
        List<Topic> topic_list=qr1.list();
        top_id=topic_list.get(jComboBox3.getSelectedIndex()).getTopic_id();
        System.out.println("Topic ID is "+top_id);
        Query qr2=ses.createQuery("from Test as t where t.import_level=:import_level and t.import_level_id=:import_level_id");
        qr2.setParameter("import_level", topicimport);
        qr2.setInteger("import_level_id",top_id);
        List<Test> test_list=qr2.list();
        //Field[] fields = null;
        System.out.println("Size of test_list is"+test_list.size());
        //Iterator<Test> itr=test_list.iterator();
        int[] test_id=new int[test_list.size()];

        for(int j=0;j<test_list.size();j++)
        {
            System.out.println("Test_List Import Wale me agaya");
            //fields=t.getClass().getDeclaredFields();    
            test_id[j]=test_list.get(j).getId();
            System.out.println("test_id: is "+test_id[j]);
        }
        System.out.println("Size of test_id array is "+test_id.length);
        for(int j=0;j<test_id.length;j++)
        {
            System.out.println("test_id now is "+j);
            int studentid=98;
            String sqlquery="SELECT ST.ID id,ST.STUDENT_ID student_id,ST.attemptNumber attempt_Number,ST.TEST_ID testId,ST.TEST_ID student_test_id,T.description description,T.test_duration test_duration,T.test_score Test_Score,ST.SCHEDULED_START_TIME_BEGIN scheduled_start_time_begin,ST.SCHEDULED_START_TIME_END scheduled_start_time_end,ST.TEST_START_DATE test_start_date,ST.LAST_ACTIVE_TIME test_last_active_time,ST.TEST_ATTEMPTED test_attempted,ST.ALLOW_VIEW_REPORT allow_view_report FROM student_test as ST,test as T WHERE ST.PAYMENT_STATUS='A' AND ST.TEST_ID = T.id AND ST.STUDENT_ID='"+studentid+"' AND ST.TEST_ATTEMPTED='0' AND T.id='"+test_id[j]+"' ORDER BY ST.ID";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            java.sql.Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school_db","root","");
            Statement pst=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            rs=pst.executeQuery(sqlquery);
            System.out.println(rs.getRow());
            System.out.println(rs.toString());
            jTable1.revalidate();
            jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            //jTable1.revalidate();
            /*SessionFactory sf1;
            Configuration cfg1=new Configuration();
            System.out.println("join query me agaya");
            cfg1.configure("hiber_config/hibernate.cfg.xml");
            sf1=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
            Session ses1=sf1.openSession();
            ses1.beginTransaction();
            ses1.doWork(new Work()
            {
                @Override
                public void execute(java.sql.Connection cnctn) throws SQLException 
                {
                    java.sql.PreparedStatement pst=cnctn.prepareStatement(sqlquery);
                    rs=pst.executeQuery();
                    System.out.println(rs.toString());
                }

            });
            ses1.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        ses.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("Test Data Retrieved");
        ses.close();*/
        } 
}
    catch(HibernateException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
}
```

**my code is working here correctly and i am able to retrieve all the resultset but in jtable i am only getting the last loop record not every loop record
Please help me**

```
private void search_by_topic() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try
        {

            SessionFactory sf;
            Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
            System.out.println("search_by_topic me agaya");
            cfg.configure("hiber_config/hibernate.cfg.xml");
            sf=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
            Session ses=sf.openSession();
            ses.beginTransaction();
            Query qr1=ses.createQuery("from Topic where chapter_id=:chapter_id");
            qr1.setParameter("chapter_id", chap_id);
            List<Topic> topic_list=qr1.list();
            top_id=topic_list.get(jComboBox3.getSelectedIndex()).getTopic_id();
            System.out.println("Topic ID is "+top_id);
            Query qr2=ses.createQuery("from Test as t where t.import_level=:import_level and t.import_level_id=:import_level_id");
            qr2.setParameter("import_level", topicimport);
            qr2.setInteger("import_level_id",top_id);
            List<Test> test_list=qr2.list();
            //Field[] fields = null;
            System.out.println("Size of test_list is"+test_list.size());
            //Iterator<Test> itr=test_list.iterator();
            int[] test_id=new int[test_list.size()];

            for(int j=0;j<test_list.size();j++)
            {
                System.out.println("Test_List Import Wale me agaya");
                //fields=t.getClass().getDeclaredFields();    
                test_id[j]=test_list.get(j).getId();
                System.out.println("test_id: is "+test_id[j]);
            }
            System.out.println("Size of test_id array is "+test_id.length);
            for(int j=0;j<test_id.length;j++)
            {
                System.out.println("test_id now is "+j);
                int studentid=98;
                String sqlquery="SELECT ST.ID id,ST.STUDENT_ID student_id,ST.attemptNumber attempt_Number,ST.TEST_ID testId,ST.TEST_ID student_test_id,T.description description,T.test_duration test_duration,T.test_score Test_Score,ST.SCHEDULED_START_TIME_BEGIN scheduled_start_time_begin,ST.SCHEDULED_START_TIME_END scheduled_start_time_end,ST.TEST_START_DATE test_start_date,ST.LAST_ACTIVE_TIME test_last_active_time,ST.TEST_ATTEMPTED test_attempted,ST.ALLOW_VIEW_REPORT allow_view_report FROM student_test as ST,test as T WHERE ST.PAYMENT_STATUS='A' AND ST.TEST_ID = T.id AND ST.STUDENT_ID='"+studentid+"' AND ST.TEST_ATTEMPTED='0' AND T.id='"+test_id[j]+"' ORDER BY ST.ID";
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                java.sql.Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school_db","root","");
                Statement pst=con.createStatement();
                rs=pst.executeQuery(sqlquery);
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Table me Agaaya");
                    System.out.println("Number of rows:- "+rs.getRow());
                    System.out.println(rs.toString());
                }
            }
            ses.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("Test Data Retrieved");
            ses.close(); 
    }
    catch(HibernateException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
}
```

**this is my code and its working fine in system.out.println it showing all data now can u tell me how to pass this data in jtable and to let you know when i use dbutils its also retrieve column name automatically and i am not giving the column name in jtable manually**

Answer (score 0):

> i know jtablename.setmodel(dbutils.setresultsettotable(rs));

Well DBUtils creates a single TableModel

> but in jtable i am only getting the last loop record not every loop record

You keep replacing the old TableModel with a new TableModel.

So you have two choices:

1. You need to create multiple tables, one for each TableModel and add each JTable to the frame
2. You need to copy the data from each TableModel into a master TableModel and then display the master TableModel into in single JTable. So this means that outside of the loop your create a DefaultTableModel with just the column names and 0 rows of data. Then instead each loop your then copy each row of data from the DBUtils model to your main TableModel. Then outside the loop your create the table using the main TableModel.

Edit:

The basic structure of the code would be something like:

```
// Create an empty table model

String[] columnNames = {"Column1", "Column2", ...};
DefaultTableModel groupModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames,0);

...

// loop for all the ids

for(int j=0;j<test_id.length;j++)
{
      ... 

    // copy the data from the idc table model to the group table model

    DefaultTableModel idModel = DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs);

    for (int i = 0; I < idModel.getRowCount())
    {
        Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();

        for (int j = 0; j < rsModel.getColumnCount()
            row.addElement( rsModel.getValueAt(i, j); 

        groupModel.addRow( row );
    }
}

JTable table = new JTable( groupModel );
```

Comment: can u please correct the code it will help me alot as i am fresher in java

Comment: @LovePoet we are not here to write your code. You learn by trying. I gave you the general structure of what the code might look like. So take the time to understand the concept of how TableModles work and fill in the blanks.